# Excel Formula to Extract Monthly Amounts

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

I need to retrieve monthly spend from one worksheet to another based on a drop-down reference. This is how my data reference worksheet looks like this:

```
**Account      Type           March     April**      
IT             Engineer      $16,992    $19,116     
PMO         Technical Mgr    $2,124     $3,324  
Finance        Engineer      $2,471     $2,471  
IT            QA             $4,455     $2,124
```

In my summary worksheet, I have a column for with a drop-down for account and would like to retrieve monthly data based on account type. If I select account type PMO, it would retrieve the monthly figures from the PMO entries in the data worksheet.

```
**Account     March     April**      
IT           $16,992    $19,116     
PMO          $2,124     $3,324
```

I believe I need use a IF/Conditional formula but can't figure it out.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd probably use a Pivot table and filter that report for the account you want.

Comment: The SumIf or SumIfs functions will do what you want

Comment: in your second table should IT for march be 16992 or 21447?

Answer (score 1):

The `vlookup` function is what you need.

Here are descriptions of [when](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-%E2%80%94-When-and-how-to-use-it-9a86157a-5542-4148-a536-724823014785) and [how](https://www.timeatlas.com/vlookup-tutorial/) to use `vlookup`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data reference table starts at `A1 on Sheet 1` and the data output table starts at `A1 on Sheet 2`, use this formula:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet2!$A2)
```